# React JS and errors in external script. Failsafe or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

I am intending to load an external `<script>` tag in my React component and add an external JS code in my webpage this way:

```
componentDidMount () 
{
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "https://some-site.com/tracking.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

My concern is:

- If the external script has some errors, throws exceptions or does not
  work at all (does not load), will it break my React component?
- Will the react continue its life cycle?
- Will my page will still be rendered?

Does the browser run the external script as another thread and is this type of  loading JS fail safe for my page?

Comment: The real question here is why are you trying to include the script this way?  Do you want to add an additional copy of the script every time your component mounts?  You probably want this in a static file, not a in a React component.

Comment: I had to do the same to load an heavy library who were breaking or slowing too much the build. It has no impact on your react code. It just insert into your main page a script tag with what you want and that's it. It's better to add it directly on your index.html page, in my case I couldn't do that, but if you can, do this

Comment: Why don't you try and test it manually? Create a temporary .js file with some jibberish text in your project and import it with a relative url. That way you'll find out.

Comment: @jmargolisvt - this is external file with google tracking code, facebook pixels, google conversion tracking, and some custom stuff. I will initialize some values from REACT (prices, IDs, config values and etc). The component will be mounted only once. React component also can be lazy loaded with Ajax, so, its not guaranteed that if I added it as a static file, the init data will be available when the JS file is loaded.